# Retrieve a person column having multiple users...need information on all the options available

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

How to retrieve a person column having multiple users... need information on all the options available.

I need this column information to break inheritance on item creation and add users from this columns as contributors to the item(discussion board).

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple-people field values like below:

1. Directly get its ID then retrieve the info from users list via ID

[image]

1. Get the expected properties in one request

[image]

More referene:

- https://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html